# Implicitly call Activity, modify it's layout and method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I dont think my question can be possible but I want to be sure.

If you call implicitly activity like this:

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 c.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

**1) Is it posibble add some views ?**

I want it's layout should like this:

at the top, myViewGroup(or a just view like Admob Banner)

then,Implicitly called activity's ViewGroup

**2) Is it possible to do it's onCreateView method to add some code?**

I dont think these questions can be happen, because as far as I know,whenever you call implicitly Activity, Your Application is paused or stopped since it loss focus and can be gain attention on StartActivityForResult(). But my problem is Android "**webview**"  have too many bugs and bad programmed I want to use external default android device's browser with override it's onCreateView and layout.

I know of the library "**Crosswalk**", but I want to know of any other way.

Comment: External default Android web browser == WebView, so maybe you shud rethink your solution? As far as adding views to activity on start - just add some extra to your activity starting intent and process this extra on your activity.

Comment: You are wrong. external default browser is too different than webview. You don't face bugs that you face with webview. Moreover I did not get what you mean with " just add some extra to your activity starting intent and process this extra on your activity"

Comment: It seems Google has a different opinion: "New Webviews also share the same rendering engine as Chrome for Android, so rendering should be much more consistent between the WebView and Chrome.". https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: As you said new "Webviews". I have android application that is live which use webviews too much!  I dont have problems with api that higher than 15 but some devices,especially samsung and s series have too many bugs with webview(Api 10-15). As result this cause  a lot report, and force them give it bad rating.

Comment: Sorry, OP, but I have a bit of difficulty understanding your English - if my interpretation is correct your question is "Is it possible to make of web view  using different web kit than the default one for Android for API levels below KitKat. This, because the Android web view web kit is quite bogous"